# Disable ext4 journaling for website?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, nginx, ext4

`/var/www/website` contains the files that powers a website, and `/var/www/media` contains many tiny media files like images in subdirectories named after their date of creation. Deleting/pruning an entire subdirectory of many tiny files hogs the IO and slows the server to a crawl for hours.

[image]

**Problem:** I believe disabling ext4 journaling can speed up the deletion, is that true?

If so, is it advisable for the main website files at `/var/www/website` to have journaling disabled as well, since they both reside in the same ext4 filesystem `/dev/md4`.

[image]

Comment: Why even configure a journalizing filesystem if you are just going to gut its primary feature.  Try using ext2 if you want to run this way.  I wish you luck and a lot of time waiting for fscks!

Comment: It was the default filesystem that came with Ubuntu 12.04 which is being used for the web server.

Comment: I guess that is why one might not want to do a default installation.

Comment: How about the `data=writeback` option instead of disabling journaling completely? I heard that ex4 without journaling is faster than ext2.

Comment: @mdpc, ext4 without journaling still has many advantages over ext2.

Comment: If it is possible in principle to change the FS then you should have a look at FS comparisons. Probably a different FS does this special task better than ext4. Or you make your own comparison.

Comment: Will eventually move the file storage to its own server, thats when I can use a different FS. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tune2fs -O ^journal` to remove the journal from the fs while it is unmounted, or mount it with the `-o noload` option to disable the journal ( temporary for the latter ), but this will make filesystem corruption more likely in the event of a crash or power fail, and at the least, will require a lengthy `fsck` after.

Comment: I guess I will stick is `data=writeback`